# Passing variables to a well format URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess is something like this

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  search.php?keyword=$1 [L]
```

and it correctly displays results for `example.org/search/tomato`

but now i'd like to pass variables to it, but when i do it like

`example.org/search/tomato?color=green`

it doesn't work.

what's the common practice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  search.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
```

> **QSA|qsappend** When the replacement URI contains a query string, the
>   default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query
>   string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA]
>   flag causes the query strings to be combined.